# EF Code-First One-to-one relationship using FluentAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-fluent-api

I have two FluentAPI Class.I used EF Code First approach. One is ClientAdmin and another is school.I want to make Id of ClientAdmin to be primary key of school table

my ClientAdmin FluentAPI class looks like this

```
public ClientAdminMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("ClientAdmin");
            this.HasKey(v => v.Id);

            this.Property(v => v.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(400);
            this.Property(v => v.Email).HasMaxLength(400);
            this.Property(v => v.MetaKeywords).HasMaxLength(400);
            this.Property(v => v.MetaTitle).HasMaxLength(400);
            this.Property(v => v.PageSizeOptions).HasMaxLength(200);
        }
```

and another class is as follow

```
public SchoolMapper()
        {
            this.ToTable("School");
            this.HasKey(bp => bp.Id);
            this.Property(bp => bp.Title).IsRequired();

            this.HasRequired(bp => bp.Language)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(bp => bp.LanguageId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        }
```

how can i achieve this?Please help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you need a `one-to-one` relationship with the `ClientAdmin` being the principal in such relationship.

When using code first and you want to create a `one-to-one` in this fashion the only thing you must do is indicate to EF which entity is the **principal** and which one will be the **dependent**.

Also you'll have to decide whether you want to expose the navigation property from the principal to the dependent and/or in the other way around.

Let's say you want to mark `ClientAdmin` as the principal, thus `School` will be the dependent and there'll be a navigation property from `ClientAdmin` to the `School` and vice versa. In this case, as is your goal, the primary key for the principal entity will also be the primary key for the dependent entity.

For that to happen you have to declare those properties on your **POCOs** and configure the entity type configuration classes to create the relationship.

Something like the below set up, should do the trick:

> Add the navigation property to the principal entity.

```
public class ClientAdmin
{
    ...

    public School School { get; set; }
}
```

> Add the navigation property to the dependent entity.

```
public class School
{
    ...

    public ClientAdmin ClientAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

> Setup the entity type configuration on one of your entity mappers. The below sets up the dependent entity - School:

```
public class SchoolMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<School>
{
    public SchoolMapper()
    {
        //your other mapping config.

        //add the one-to-one mapping.

        HasRequired(x => x.ClientAdmin)
            .WithRequiredDependent(x => x.School)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

That should give you the desired relationship between `ClientAdmin` and `School` entities. Let me know how it works for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. But still it not work.if I add one relationship in schoolmapper. is it possible to do like this??   this.HasRequired(bp => bp.ClientAdmin)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(bp => bp.Id).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

Comment: @shahharshil sure, that's possible, but it's no longer a one-to-one anymore, it'll be a one-to-many and that's a completely different story then. It's not the same to say a ClientAdmin has one or more Schools than it must be only one ClientAdmin by School and one School per ClientAdmin (a one-to-one). You should get that from the context of your problem.